# Ubuntu MATE - Resolution stuck at 640x480

Tags: graphics, display-resolution, xrandr

I have just installed Ubuntu MATE and my resolution is stuck at 640x480. I have tried using both `xrandr` and the video settings to change this, but 640 is the only option I see.

Here is a screenshot showing the problem and some details from `xrandr`:

[image: Details]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of the computer? I can see that it's probably an "old laptop", but knowing specifically which one may make it easier to offer a potential solution.

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg-query --show --showformat='${db:Status-Status}\n' linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot shows an SIS 771/671 graphics adapter, which has a rather notorious history with Linux. That said, I did find in my "Notebook of Ubuntu Solutions" an old config file that would get this device to work with Ubuntu 12.04.

> **NOTE:** *I do not have access to a notebook with this particular video card, so cannot test this solution with a modern version of Ubuntu.*

Here's how you may be able to resolve your resolution issue:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create a new Xorg config file:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
2. Paste this next section into the file:

   ```
   Section "Device"
     Identifier "Generic Video Card"
       VendorName  "Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]"
           BoardName   "771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter"
       Busid "PCI:1:0:0"
       Driver "vesa"
       Screen 0
           Option "UseFBDev" "true"
           Option "DPMS"
           Option "ShadowFB"
           Option "MaxXFBMem"
           VideoRam 262016
           Option "RenderAccel" "true"
           Option "AllowGLXWithComposite" "true"
           Option "backingstore" "true"
           Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
   EndSection

   Section "Monitor"
       Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
       Vendorname    "Generic LCD Display"
       Modelname     "LCD Panel 1280x800"
       HorizSync 20-107
       VertRefresh 50-185
       modeline  "800x600@56" 36.0 800 824 896 1024 600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync
       modeline  "800x600@60" 40.0 800 840 968 1056 600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync
       modeline  "1280x768@60" 80.14 1280 1344 1480 1680 768 769 772 795 -hsync +vsync
       modeline  "1280x720@60" 74.48 1280 1336 1472 1664 720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync
       modeline  "1280x800@60" 83.46 1280 1344 1480 1680 800 801 804 828 -hsync +vsync
       Gamma    1.0
   EndSection

   Section "Screen"
       Identifier    "Default Screen"
       Monitor       "Configured Monitor"
       Device        "Configured Video Device"
       Defaultdepth  24
       SubSection "Display"
           Depth     24
           Virtual   1280    768
           Modes     "1280x768@60"    "1280x720@60"    "800x600@60"    "1280x800@60"    "800x600@56"
       EndSubSection
   EndSection

   Section "Module"
       Load "dri"
       Load "dbe" # Double-Buffering Extension
       Load "v4l" # Video for Linux
       Load "extmod"
       Load "type1"
       Load "freetype"
       Load "glx" # 3D layer
       Load "GLcore"
       Load "i2c"
       Load "bitmap"
       Load "ddc"
       Load "int10"
       Load "vbe"
       Load "speedo"
       Load "record"
   EndSection

   Section "DRI"
       Mode 0666
   EndSection
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Reboot

Hopefully this solution will continue to work

Comment: thank you @matigo it worked